# Convert an object to bytes array in c#

Tags: c#, serialization

I want to convert an object to a bytes array, everything that I found is about converting an object which is set with serializable attribute before, but I have some classes which aren't serializable and I can't set them as serializable.
My question is that how can I convert an unserializable object to bytes array or convert an unserializable object to a serializable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865104/convert-any-object-to-a-byte

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923196/converting-non-serializable-classes-to-a-byte-array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446547/how-to-convert-an-object-to-a-byte-array-in-c-sharp

Comment: I think in addition to the links, by definition, if you have an **un**serializable object, you can't convert it to serializable ... (linguistics ... )